# IOS 6 to Swift2 update Slider

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

any chance someone to help me in this code? 
it is a Slider that changes the size of the Fonts in a Label. this worked in IOS6 but I am trying to run on Swift 2.
Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func defaultSlider1(sender: UISlider) {

        UISlider *slide = (UISlider *)sender;
        int fonts = (int)(slide.value);
        NSString *newtext = NSlog("%d", fonts);
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fonts];
        label.text = newtext;

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Why are you comparing an iOS version (iOS 6) to a language version (Swift 2)?

Comment: Swift isn't just a different way of declaring the functions you put your Objective-C into. What did you try?

Comment: maybe you should learn how to program using swift, I see `;`, `[...]`, `NSLog(...)`, casts using `(int)(...)` - all things that you do in objective-c but not in swift.

Comment: @rmaddy The code shows a lot of errors, so I think is because was written in Objective-C instead of Swift.

Comment: @Tommy I tried many different options I read in the documentation, but I could not make it work :(

Comment: @luk2302 I am studying and learning Swift Mr. Luk, that is why I am using this forum. If anyone here has no doubts or want to learn something this forum would not exist. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following example ([**Demo**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2thda.gif)):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    private var slider: UISlider!
    private var label: UILabel!

    private let minimumFontSize: Float = 16
    private let maximumFontSize: Float = 48


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let width: CGFloat  = view.bounds.width / 2
        let height: CGFloat = 44.0

        let size    = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        let origin  = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x - (width / 2), y: self.view.center.y)

        createSlider(origin, size: size)
        createLabel(origin, size: size)
        sliderAction()
    }

    func createSlider(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {

        let frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

        self.slider = UISlider(frame: frame)
        self.slider.addTarget(self,
            action: Selector("sliderAction"),
            forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        self.slider.minimumValue = minimumFontSize
        self.slider.maximumValue = maximumFontSize

        view.addSubview(self.slider)
    }

    func createLabel(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {
        let labelOrigin = CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: origin.y + size.height)
        let frame = CGRect(origin: labelOrigin, size: size)

        self.label = UILabel(frame: frame)
        self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        view.addSubview(self.label)
    }

    func sliderAction() {
        let fontSize = CGFloat(self.slider.value)

        self.label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)
        self.label.text = "\(Int(fontSize))"
    }

}
```

---

In case you're using **Storyboards**:

- Add UISlider and UILabel to your View Controller Scene on the Storyboard
- Insert `@IBOutlet`s for each control (`Ctrl+Drag` from the control on the Storyboard to code, choose `Outlet` from `Connection` list)
- Insert `@IBAction` for slider's `Value Changed` event (`Ctrl+Drag` from the slider control on the Storyboard to code, choose `Action` from `Connection` list)

You may end up with something like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.slider.minimumValue = 16
        self.slider.maximumValue = 48

        self.sliderAction()
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChangedAction(sender: UISlider) {
        self.sliderAction()
    }

    private func sliderAction() {
        let fontSize = CGFloat(self.slider.value)

        self.label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)
        self.label.text = "\(Int(fontSize))"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will try to adapt to my Slider/Label added via Object Library at least I have a start. Cheers.

Comment: I tried to add yur func sliderAtcion to the IBAction but there is an error "Value of type (UISlider) has no member 'value' any idea? Do you have this code for Object Library? instead of pragmatically? ;)

Comment: That was perfect I did not set an IBOutlet to the slider only an IBAction maybe that is why I was having problem to make it work. Now is perfect Thanks again....